# NoSuchMethodError on login but working fine to other pc

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websphere

I have a working java web app deployed in WebSphere.

But after an automatic update from windows, I am getting a **NoSuchMethodError**. I was able to direct to app's log in page. But every time I log in, it gives me this error.

Here's the full error.

```html
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.getNativeResponse(Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
Error Stack: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.getNativeResponse(Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; 
     at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:109) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:93) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) 
     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) 
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) 
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

I tried to deploy the war file to other pc and it's working fine. I even copied his .ear folder and replace my .ear folder but still no luck.

I compared my java version, jar versions and websphere version and all are the same.

I don't have any other idea to fix this. Please Help!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I used the IP of my colleague as host name in my datasource instead of localhost and I was able to log in without any error. In addition, I don't know if this has connection to my problem, when I try to debug the app, I am getting**Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.** but when I use again the IP of my colleague as host name, I can debug. Could there be problem in my laptop?

Comment: Can you share with us what is on your classpath? What applications windows updated? Also spring versions and everything that could be useful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the link as below, control your application parent first and last configuration for the class loader. Do the procedure commands in the link for your application. You can meet "no such a method Exception" in Run-time when the `WebUtils` class is located to libs both WAS internal libraries and your ear's lib. So if `getNativeResponse` method is not located in loaded internal WebUtils class. You will get this Runtime exception. You can control your jars for `WebUtils.getNativeResponse` and its signitures in **WAS** libs and **Ear's** libs. According to this case select **the parent last or first config** for 
 the class loader.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/trun_classload_server.html

Answer (score 0):

Your application almost certainly contains two separate, incompatible Spring jars in its WEB-INF/lib directory. The contents of that directory are not ordered per the specification, and the server simply puts them on the WAR class path in whatever order it gets the list from the file system. Most likely, the failing system is natively returning the list of files in that directory in a different order than the working system, and that order results in the "wrong" copy of the jar showing up earlier in the class path.

The easy solution is simply to get rid of that wrong version - Java does not allow two classes by the same name to be loaded from a single class loader, so there is literally no way to utilize multiple versions of a class packaged in a WAR. Using multiple, incompatible versions of a single technology within a single WAR module can't be done.

If you're having issues figuring out which jars are the right ones, you can verify what jars the classes come from by enabling verbose class loading (it's a checkbox on the server JVM config panel) and searching native_stderr.log to see what jar(s) the classes are coming from - the important classes are org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils and org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository. Spring is usually good about having version strings on their jars, so hopefully you can very easily see from that output what versions you have in play and which ones you'll need to remove.